# How to upload a file from Jenkins Workspace to a remote dest with ansible

Tags: docker, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I need to copy a Docker-compose file from my Jenkins workspace to a remote machine using ansible. This is what I have right now

```
---
- hosts: [...].es

  tasks:
  - name: copy Docker Compose files
    copy:
      remote_src: ~/docker-compose.yml
      dest: ./opt/ydilo/ydilo-acalls/

  - name: Run container
    become: True
    shell:
      cmd: "docker-compose up"
      chdir: ./opt/ydilo/ydilo-acalls/
```

It connects to the host properly because the docker-compose up command have be done. But I can't copy the file properly. I have changed the ~ to - in the remote_src but It dosen't changed anything.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

In your ansible play, the **copy** task

```
  - name: copy Docker Compose files
    copy:
      remote_src: ~/docker-compose.yml
      dest: ./opt/ydilo/ydilo-acalls/
```

The **remote_src** attribute is not the right one; **remote_src** as per ansible docs [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-remote_src), should be either yes or no, and it influence the behaviour while executing the **copy** task; However, you need to add the **src** attribute which defines the path of the file to be copied.

Should be something like that (Supposing you provided right paths on both local and remote hosts)

```
  - name: copy Docker Compose files
    copy:
      src: ~/docker-compose.yml
      dest: ./opt/ydilo/ydilo-acalls/
```